# Image rotation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, transformations, image-processing, 2d, raster-image

I would like to rotate a raster image by an arbitrary angle. I don't really care for speed: the rotation should be of highest quality possible. Could someone please suggest a suitable algorithm?

I'm familiar with the [rotation by three shears](http://www.leptonica.com/rotation.html#ROTATION-BY-SHEAR) but I'm not sure if the shears would not cause too much aliasing/blurring.

Comment: The 'rotation by area mapping' algorithm described at http://www.leptonica.com/rotation.html looks like a good place to start

Answer (score 4):

It speed does not matter, I suggest to use a truncated sinc or a Lanczos isotropic kernel: to compute a target pixel, you back-rotate the filter and  convolve it with the image. Since it is isotropic, it is separable and you can even use a square filter parallel to the axis of the source image.